# Jquery ajax - странный ответ

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Добрый день!
Помогите побороть проблему с ajax. Есть такая функция

```
function ajax_message_delete(id, zadanie_id) {

$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_script/messages_window.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'action=delete_message&id=' + id + '&zadanie_id=' + zadanie_id,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('.infrsend').html(data);
            $('#center_box').slimScroll({ height:150, start : 'bottom' }) ;
        }
    }
});
```

}

После обработки отображается странное дополнение к результату, скрин по ссылке

[image: Imgur]

Обработка на php (причем не имеет значение что будет с за ответ с серверной стороны, можно и просто "1" отправить):

```
    if ($action == 'delete_message' && $id > 0 && $zadanie_id > 0) {

    //если админ
    if($moderator['status'] == 'admin' || $moderator['funct'][13] == 1) {

        //q("delete from `users_messages` where `id` = '$id'");
        $messages = load_messages_window(0, $zadanie_id, 1);

    }
    //*

    //если не админ
    else {

        //узнаем с кем мы общались
        $q = q("select `user_to` from `users_messages` where `user_form` = '" . $_SESSION['user'][0] . "' and `id` = '$id'");
        $user_to = mysql_fetch_row($q);
        //*

        q("delete from `users_messages` where `user_form` = '" . $_SESSION['user'][0] . "' and `id` = '$id'");
        $messages = load_messages_window($user_to[0], $zadanie_id);

    }
    //*

    echo '<div class="center_box" id="center_box">' . $messages . '</div>';

}
```

Comment: что у вас там на серверной стороне творится? показывайте код

Comment: ответ у вас приходит в `json` формате. Видимо вы реально скинули не тот кусок кода, который исполняется на сервере.